# Invalid Identifier for input parameter variables on Oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will grab all columns from a view and generate XML data for it on a CLOB.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PaGenerarServicioXML(vIdViaje IN NUMBER, vIDCliente IN varchar)
IS
ServicioXML CLOB;
BEGIN

  SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML (q'!
       SELECT *
      FROM VwServicio VwS
      WHERE VwS.Identificador_Viaje = vIdViaje 
      AND VwS.Identificador_Cliente = vIdCliente
      !')
    INTO ServicioXML
    FROM DUAL;
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ServicioXML);
END;

EXECUTE PaGenerarServicioXML(2,'304560326')
```

The stored procedure is saved correctly.

When I execute this stored procedure, the following errors are thrown:

```
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
ORA-00904: "VIDCLIENTE": invalid identifier ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 176
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 7
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 164
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SQL_MBFTRUKIWLGITBRTRBBHFHTSA.PAGENERARSERVICIOXML", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

If I remove the `AND` statement in the `WHERE` clause, the error changes to it not identifying `VIDVIAJE` as valid. Why is it not accepting the input variables I just created?

Inside the `VwServicio` view, `Identificador_Viaje` is an `INT` datatype, and `Identificador_Cliente` is a `VARCHAR`, so I really don't understand where the issue is.

Comment: As you may see, SQL text in `getxml` is a string. It doesn't (and cannot) know anything about external variables, because it is executed in different transaction with its own content like `execute immediate`. You need to inject that values into the SQL text

Answer (score 2):

Your query is a string and `DBMS_XMLGEN` doesn't know anything about external context when it executes the inner query. To pass parameters to it you need to use this signature of the function:

```
DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML (
   ctx          IN ctxHandle,
   dtdOrSchema  IN number := NONE)
 RETURN CLOB;
```

Then create a context from general cursor and pass parameters here:

```
dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(cursor(
  SELECT *
  FROM VwServicio VwS
  WHERE VwS.Identificador_Viaje = vIdViaje 
    AND VwS.Identificador_Cliente = vIdCliente
))
```

Putting it all together, you'll have something like this:

> ```
> create table t
> as
> select level - 1 as id
> from dual
> connect by level < 3
> ```

> ```
> create table t_child
> as
> select mod(level, 6) as id
>   , level as child_id
> from dual
> connect by level < 18
> ```

> ```
> create function f_get_children_xml(
>   p_id in int
> ) return clob
> is
>   l_cur sys_refcursor;
> begin
>   open l_cur for
>     select *
>     from t_child
>     where t_child.id = p_id
>   ;
>   return dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
>     ctx => dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(queryString => l_cur)
>   );
> end;
> /
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select f_get_children_xml(id)
> from t
> ```

| F_GET_CHILDREN_XML(ID) |
| --- |
| ``` <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROWSET> <ROW> <ID>0</ID> <CHILD_ID>6</CHILD_ID> </ROW> <ROW> <ID>0</ID> <CHILD_ID>12</CHILD_ID> </ROW> </ROWSET> ``` |
| ``` <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROWSET> <ROW> <ID>1</ID> <CHILD_ID>1</CHILD_ID> </ROW> <ROW> <ID>1</ID> <CHILD_ID>7</CHILD_ID> </ROW> <ROW> <ID>1</ID> <CHILD_ID>13</CHILD_ID> </ROW> </ROWSET> ``` |

Or the same with plain SQL:

> ```
> select
>   id,
>   dbms_xmlgen.getxml(dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(
>     cursor(select * from t_child where t_child.id = t.id)
>   )) as dependent_xml
> from t
> ```

| ID | DEPENDENT_XML |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ``` <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROWSET> <ROW> <ID>0</ID> <CHILD_ID>6</CHILD_ID> </ROW> <ROW> <ID>0</ID> <CHILD_ID>12</CHILD_ID> </ROW> </ROWSET> ``` |
| 1 | ``` <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROWSET> <ROW> <ID>1</ID> <CHILD_ID>1</CHILD_ID> </ROW> <ROW> <ID>1</ID> <CHILD_ID>7</CHILD_ID> </ROW> <ROW> <ID>1</ID> <CHILD_ID>13</CHILD_ID> </ROW> </ROWSET> ``` |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=571b1ef4ad540df09a8f30d755249ff5)*